# I need to play next song when click on on-click button

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

```
var song1 = $('#sound-1');
var song2 = $('#sound-2');

var audioArray = [song1, song2];
var i=0;
var lastPlayedFile = null;
$(".click").click(function(){
    if(lastPlayedFile !== null) {
        lastPlayedFile[0].currentTime = 0;
        lastPlayedFile.trigger('pause');
    }
    if (i< audioArray.length){
        lastPlayedFile = audioArray[i];
        audioArray[i].trigger('play');
        i++;
    } else if (i>=audioArray.length){
        i = 0;
        lastPlayedFile = audioArray[0];
        audioArray[i].trigger('play');
    };
});
```

This code is not working for me and I am using firefox web browser. Is there any issue in this code?

Comment: Please provide the code for the element with ID 'sound-1 and/or 'sound-2''. It's hard to know if this code is correct without that.

Comment: What does this have to do with PureScript?

Comment: <audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Ludwig_van_Beethoven_-_Symphonie_5_c-moll_-_1._Allegro_con_brio.ogg" id="sound-1" controls></audio>
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Anthem_of_Europe_%28US_Navy_instrumental_short_version%29.ogg" controls id="sound-2"></audio>
<hr>
<button class="click">
    Click to play
</button>

Comment: I have added above my HTML part

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure you are correctly using the `<audio>` tag like shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_audio.asp). The browser will pick up the first recognized source:

   `<audio controls>
      // browser tries to fetch horse.ogg first
      <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      // browser tries to fetch horse.mp3 if the above couldn't be recognized
      <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      // if none files are valid the browser falls back with a message
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>`
2. Make sure also that your files you are trying to access do actually exist. I have tried finding them but I got a 404 response.
3. Also this line of code won't do anything:

   `lastPlayedFile[0].currentTime = 0;`

   make sure you have a `currentTime` property set on each of the `audioArray` elements (`song1` and `song2`)